# File System Filter Driver - File Name Breakage

Tags: filesystems, driver, windows-kernel, filter-driver

I am currently developing a file system filter driver.

What the filter driver does is to check which files are being created and deleted and to leave a log.

In most cases, this filter driver works well.

Sometimes, however, TargetFileObject-> FileName gets strangely broken into Unicode strings.

I do not know why this is happening.

When this happens, a BSOD occurs.

(The cause of BSOD is 0x19 Bad Pool Header.) It occurs when calling ExFreePool function after saving file name and logging.

Should I ignore this situation? Or is there a way to validate something like this?

[image]

The above picture would probably be "\Windows\..."

Who has the same problem and has solved it?

-------------------------Modify ------------------------

Below is a part of my source code.

```
FLT_PREOP_CALLBACK_STATUS FLTAPI MinifilterPreCallBack
(
    __inout PFLT_CALLBACK_DATA pData,
    __in PCFLT_RELATED_OBJECTS pFltObjects,
    __deref_out_opt PVOID* ppCompletionContext
)
{

    ...

    if(KeGetCurrentIrql() != PASSIVE_LEVEL)
    {
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }
    if(PsGetCurrentProcessId()==4)
    {
        return FLT_PREOP_SUCCESS_NO_CALLBACK;
    }

    ...

    Status = IoVolumeDeviceToDosName(Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->DeviceObject, &DriveName);

    ...

    UNICODE_STRING FileName = Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName;
    WCHAR* FullFilePath = ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, (DriveName.Length + FileName.Length) * 2 + 10);
    swprintf(FullFilePath, L"FILE_CREATED %wZ%wZ", &DriveName, &Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject->FileName);

    ... // Save Log or DbgPrint ...

    ExFreePool(FullFilePath);
}
```

It operates roughly as above.

Find the drive name as IoVolumeDeviceToDosName (\ Device \ HarddiskVolume1 -> C: )
Find the file name (FileObject-> FileName)

By allocating the buffer size with ExAllocatePool
Obtain the full path with swprintf.

I do not know why this is an error.

When BSOD occurs, it is always the case that the broken string comes in as above.

Comment: obviously the `FileName.Buffer` already was freed by call  `ExFreePool` (this and give broken first 2 Unicode symbols (4 bytes - sizeof(pvoid) on x86)) - memory returned to the pool. notable also that `FileName.Length==0`. so here was double free. and may be this you and do this, without view code hard say. and why you at all try free file name ? this have sense only if you return `STATUS_REPARSE`. and at all - why you free name by `ExFreePool` but not by `RtlFreeUnicodeString` ? replace to `RtlFreeUnicodeString` for begin - are you still got this bsod ?

Comment: I never freed the same memory twice.

As far as I know, releasing the same memory in a row considers itself a blue screen.

I'm not sure about STATUS_REPARSE. I can not search well.

What I think is important is that swprintf () causes an overflow due to a broken string.

And I tried using _snwprintf to avoid overflow, but the same problem occurred.

I want to be able to filter out broken strings and ignore them.

Comment: in screen you show `FileObject.FileName` when in code show absolute another (`FullFilePath`) (and for what `NonPagedPool` here ?). how i say this case of begin string change (in screen) due `FileObject.FileName.Buffer`  already free

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not have enough English. I can not read your English well.

Can you explain it easily?

Answer (score 1):

`FileName` in any fileobject structure be it `Data->Iopb->TargetFileObject` or `pFltObjects` need not be always there. The OS could free up that memory whenever required.

The `FileName` is valid only in `Pre-Create` callback function. 
In general you need to store the file name in your own structures attached to file object as stream/file/handle contexts. And use that in other callbacks.

Comment: So what you're saying is that in PreCallBack I need to store the filename in the global variable or allocated memory space of my driver and use it in PostCallBack?

Is FileName not valid in PostCallback?

I think they are valid in PostCallback, but ...

I will try and comment.

Comment: They guarantee that it would be valid in PreCreate callback. In other IRPs it may or may not be.

Answer (score 1):

buffer overrun.

The length of L"FILE_CREATED " is more than 10. so the buffer is not enough.